# How to reference right value of `i` in a callback in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // call a function that open a new "thread"
    myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
        alert(result.title[i]);
    });                                             
}
```

The `.geocode` function (that is not mine, so I can't edit) open a new "thread" of execution.

When I try to print title on each step, I get always the last possible value of `i`.

How can I keep a reference to the right value of `i` for each iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a closure within the loop;

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // call a function that open a new "thread"
    (function (i) {
        myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
            alert(result.title[i]);
        });
    }(i));                                             
}
```

So here we're creating a function;

```
(function (i) {
    myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
        alert(result.title[i]);
    });
});
```

... which accepts one parameter named `i`, and launches the geocode request. By adding the `(i)` to the end of the declaration of a function expression, we run the function straight away and pass it the current value of `i`.

```
(function (i) {
    myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
        alert(result.title[i]);
    });
}(i));
```

It doesn't matter that a variable `i` already exists at a higher scope than the closure, because the local declaration of `i` overrides it. Either the variable we pass *to* the closure, or the name the closure calls the variable could be different;

```
(function (anotherVariable) {
    myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
        alert(result.title[anotherVariable]);
    });
}(aVariable));
```

**Alternately** you could also extract the logic to another function (I prefer it, but it's less *cool*):

```
function geocode(i) {
   myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, function(results, status) {
       alert(result.title[i]);
   });
}

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    geocode(i);                                            
}
```

The problem is down to the *same* `i` variable being used by the callback functions; which, as you've discovered, has moved on by the time the callback executes. Both of the above solutions creates another variable for each iteration, and it is this that the callback operates on.

Comment: Why do you put "(i)" at the end of the closure (function (i)?

Comment: @markzzz: It invokes the function straight away and passes the current value of `i` to it. Inside the closure `i` is the local parameter which has just been passed, hence the value of `i` does not change.

Comment: Uhm...sorry...I don't understand what kind of syntax is `(function (i) { } (i));`. Is it that `(i)` that invoke `(function (i) { })`? :O

Answer (score 2):

See [JavaScript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) to understand why your code doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var callback = (function(i) {
        return function(results, status) {
            alert(result.title[i]);
        };
    })(i);

    myObject.geocode({ param1: "param" }, callback);
}
```

Comment: The `i` variable within the function whose result is assigned to `callback` variable, is `undefined`. And because of that your code actually does something like that: `alert(result.title[undefined])`.

Comment: Sorry, missed an `i`. Thanks for the heads-up!