# Javascript Animation Level: Beginner

Tags: javascript, animation, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript animations but, as I thinked, it doesn't work xD.

UPDATED DELETING PASTING MISTAKES

I tried

```
function click_home()
{
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
       setTimeout(setOpacity("div_home",i),200);
    }
};

function setOpacity(id,value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = value/10;
    document.getElementById(id).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
};
```

And HTML:

```
<td id="button_home" onclick="click_home();"> Home </td>
```

But obviously is wrong.
What can I do to do this?:)
Thanks to all replies :)

Comment: I wrote 'Hi all :D' at beginning xD

Comment: You need to tell us _why_ it's wrong; what is is not doing that you want it to do, what behaviour does it currently exhibit?

Comment: instead of div_home i think it should be button_home

Comment: @JamWaffles This is the problem: nothing happens. And I edited what's wrong and what isn't in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you've got a syntax error in the `for` loop (change the `,` to a `;`).

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`, so it can execute it periodically. What you're currently passing `setTimeout` is the **result** of executing `setOpacity("div_home",i)` (i.e. `undefined`).

```
function click_home()
{
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
       setTimeout(function () {
           setOpacity("div_home",i)
       }, 200);
    }
};
```

What you'll also find is you value of `i` will always end up being the last value, because of the scope of `i`, to fix this you need to add a new scope level. For a more detailed description on this problem, see [How to reference right value of `i` in a callback in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179862/how-to-reference-right-value-of-i-in-a-callback-in-a-loop)

```
function click_home()
{
    function delay(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
           setOpacity("div_home",i)
        }, 200);
    }

    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
       delay(i);
    }
};
```

As noted in the comments, you will find **all** of your timeouts will execute after 200ms.. to get the animation you'll need to stagger the execution. The simplest way would be to add `i` to the delay calculation; i.e. `25 * i`.

I'm not sure *why* you're setting the `opacity` and `filter` to `0` *first* in your `setOpacity` function; these resets will **immediately** be set to the values that follow.

You should also look at caching the result of `document.getElementById(id).style`, as you're looking it up 4 times (and will be 2 if you remove the unneeded resets described above).

```
function setOpacity(id,value) {
    var style = document.getElementById(id).style;

    style.opacity = value/10;
    style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
};
```

Comment: Since all the changes will happen after 200 ms, nothing will appear to happen but an immediate opacity jump.  Change 200 to i*20

Comment: Nope, this one doesn't work for me...
I thought that was for the ';' forgotten in 'setOpacity("div_home",i)' but nope.
Thanks a lot, anyway :)

Comment: @Dave: Well noticed. Updated.

Comment: @Bonny1992: This answer will get you a long way to getting it working. Putting a comment at the bottom saying "this doesn't work" doesn't help me, *or anyone else* getting you the remainder of the way (whatever the remaining problems are). *Be more specific*.

Comment: And changed 200 to i*20 but no thing appeared.

Comment: ... Sorry for my bad specification :). The resets was a try and I forgot to delete before paste here. I tried put your code, but my 'div_home' had no animation or opacity... Do you need something else? :) Sorry again :)

Comment: @Bonny1992: My code works in the test I tried; http://jsfiddle.net/2zA4K/1. Perhaps you can compare my example to the code you're using and work out where the differences lie.

Comment: @Matt: Your code on jsfiddle.net works, in fact applied to my html works [jsfiddle link updated](http://jsfiddle.net/2zA4K/2/), but on Chrome or Firefox don't...

Comment: @Bonny1992: What do you want the code to do? When I click "Home" on your example (in Chrome) the text `asndaklsndamndklmcadcmk` fades in?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, i wanted to make a div fade in and even fade out... and i wrote something inside it xD And your code is perfect, but on Chrome or Firefox don't works and I don't know why...

Comment: @Matt: Here, neither Chrome or Firefox do a fade. And I don't know why... Do you wanna try passing an archive containing all the files? If you want [Download Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?t39ydvopv5c8aab)

Comment: @Matt: Even with [script.aculo.us](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/script.aculo.us/scriptaculous_opacity_effect.htm) fade script works... :(

Comment: I tried with [Bernie Sumpton's Animator](http://berniesumption.com/software/animator/) and it works!!! :)